# What is wrong with this Create Table statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

please could you help me with this piece of code, I don't know what's wrong with it. It seems correct at simple glance but it just gets me #1064 syntax error. The MySQL version am running is 5.5

```
CREATE TABLE mytablename(
   -> id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   -> name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   -> submission_date NOT NULL TIMESTAMP,
   -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
   -> )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '-> id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -> name CHAR(100), ->
>   submission' at line 2

Comment: Well, `->` is not part of SQL syntax. Just remove all `->` strings.

Comment: Why wouldn't it know it was cut and paste from the net, though?

Answer (score 1):

Remove those arrows and try escaping the column names with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE mytablename(
    `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `submission_date` NOT NULL TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```